# Get week date range in a label

Tags: javascript, html, label

I have 3 buttons i.e for week,previous and next. On click of week button it will display the date selected in textbox  and 6 days added to it(in a range for example 26 Jun 2013-2 Jul 2013
). On click of previous button it will display as 19 Jun 2013-26 Jun 2013 in label.On click of next button it will  display 2 Jul 2013-8 Jul 2013 in label. And the process continues.I want how this will be done in javascript.

```
enter code here



  <input type="text" id="txtDateFilter" readonly="readonly"  
   style="height: 25px; width: 150px;
   font-size: medium; font-family: Times New Roman;"   runat="server"    />


    <label  id="txtdatetimeshow" runat="server" />
    <input type="button" id="showweekbtn" runat="server" value="week"/>
    <input type="button" id="sfprevbtn" runat="server" value="prev"/>
    <input type="button" id="sfnextbtn" runat="server" value="next"/>

   Javascript Code        

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
    {
    var txtDate=$("#txtDateFilter").val();
    var today=new Date();
    var day=today.getDay();
    var date=today.getDate();
    var month=today.getMonth();
    var year= today.getFullYear();
    var month_names = new Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul",   
"Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec");

    var NextDate= new Date(year, month, date);

    var weekdate=new Date(txtDate);
    weekdate.setDate(weekdate.getDate()+6);
    var Ndate=NextDate.getDate()+" "+month_names[month]+"   
"+NextDate.getFullYear()+"-"+""+weekdate.getDate()+"  
"+month_names[weekdate.getMonth()]+" "+weekdate.getFullYear();

    var nextWeekDate=new Date(weekdate);
    nextWeekDate.setDate(weekdate.getDate()+6);
    var NWdate=weekdate.getDate()+" "+month_names[weekdate.getMonth()]+" 
"+weekdate.getFullYear()+"-"+""+nextWeekDate.getDate()+" 
"+month_names[nextWeekDate.getMonth()]+" "+nextWeekDate.getFullYear();

    var prevWeekDate=new Date(NextDate);
    prevWeekDate.setDate(NextDate.getDate()-6);
    var PWdate=prevWeekDate.getDate()+" "+month_names[prevWeekDate.getMonth()]+" 
"+prevWeekDate.getFullYear()+"-"+NextDate.getDate()+" 
"+month_names[NextDate.getMonth()]+" "+NextDate.getFullYear();

    //to show previous date
    $("#sfprevbtn").click(function() 
        {
       var prevDate=new Date(year,month,date-1);
       var pdate=prevDate.getDate()+" "+month_names[month] +" "+prevDate.getFullYear();
       $("#txtDateFilter").val(pdate);


            $("#txtdatetimeshow").text(PWdate);

    });
    //to show next date
    $("#sfnextbtn").click(function()
         {

        var nextDate=new Date(year,month,date+1);
        var Ndate=nextDate.getDate()+" "+month_names[month] +"  
"+nextDate.getFullYear();
        $("#txtDateFilter").val(Ndate);


            $("#txtdatetimeshow").text(NWdate);

    });

        //to show week view
        $("#showweekbtn").click(function() 
        {

            $("#txtdatetimeshow").text(Ndate);

});


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I create a function called "getWeekInterval()". It use picked date to calculate the day which added 6 day to picked date. And show the interval in human-readable string format.

```
function getWeekInterval(){
    var start = pickedDate.getTime()+1000*3600*24*7*pointer;
    var end = start+1000*3600*24*7;
    $("#date-label").text(new Date(start).toDateString()+"~"+new Date(end).toDateString());
}
```

Then I register a button click event listener. It is responsible for recording the picked date when user change the reference day by clicking next or prev button and update the date label.

```
$("button").click(function(e){
  switch(e.target.id)
  {
      case "week-btn":
          pointer=0;
          break;
      case "prev-btn":
          pointer--;
          break;
      case "next-btn":
          pointer++;
          break;
  }
  getWeekInterval();
});
```

I tested it in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2pUJx/1/).
Try it and hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks Chickenrice.But i want in format like 26 Jun 2013. How to do that?

Comment: I updated the date presenting code. It's a tricky way but it's easy and fast if the order of month and day is not important. If you really need the format you mentioned then you have to write a function to convert the date string to dd mm yyyy by using getFullYear, getMonth, getDay functions.

Comment: Sir please provide me an example.I am stuck in this part.Can u please rectify my code and tell me the problem.